How can I convert this cottage cheese pancake recipe to waffle?
I know that the general rule for converting pancakes to waffles is add an egg and 1/3 cup of oil.  However, as you can see below this recipe has 8 eggs and no oil (except that used for cooking the pancakes.  I wondered if adding an extra egg and 1/3 cup oil would work for this recipe?   Or should I add cornstarch? I hate to waste all the ingredients until I know there is a chance it will work.
Ingredients:

2 cups cottage Cheese
8 eggs
2 teaspoons baking powder
2 teaspoons cinnamon
1 teaspoon vanilla extract
1 teaspoon Stevia
2 tablespoons Coconut Oil (for cooking)
2 cups oats, whole, dry, organic

Directions:
Mix all ingredients except oil in a blender.
Heat pan with 1 Tbsp coconut oil in each of 2 pans at low medium heat (300°). Pour 2/3 cups batter into pan and add any fruits like blueberries or apple
pieces to it.
Cook each side for 3-5 minutes.
Top with organic maple syrup or apple sauce and fruits.

I would not expect to be able to convert that recipe to a waffle at all.  That's a no-gluten, low-carb recipe with a lot of moisture.  It would be hard enough to flip as a pancake; as a waffle, there is no way it will hold together.
We have a similar high-protein ricotta pancake recipe we make periodically.  This one also cannot be turned into a waffle, the pancakes are just too delicate.
